# vertical scroll bar not activated in python treeview,How to fixed this problem?

Tags: python, treeview, scrollbar

I try to adjust vertical and horizontal scrollbar in the same treeview

- horizontal is good
- vertical is to small icon and cant scroll at all
- you can see as below picture
  ***** How to fixed this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ziiq.png)

my code:

table_header = ["ID","Machine ID","Machine Name","Outstock","Date&Time","Picture","Problem","How to fixed"]
table_width  = [40,110,210,120,280,100,100,180]

```
    table_outstock = ttk.Treeview(T2,columns=table_header,show="headings",height=20,style="table_outstock.Treeview")
    table_outstock.pack(padx=240,pady=70,expand=True,fill='both') 
    
    #### ปรับ table style ####
    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("Treeview.Heading",font=(None,10))
    style.configure("table_outstock.Treeview",font=(None,15),rowheight=20)

    for h,w in zip(table_header,table_width):
        table_outstock.column(h,width=w)
        table_outstock.heading(h,text=h)


    # Create vertical scrollbar
    y_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(T2, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=table_outstock.yview)
    y_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill='y')
    table_outstock.configure(yscrollcommand=y_scrollbar.set)
    

    # Create horizontal scrollbar
    x_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(T2, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=table_outstock.xview)     
    x_scrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill='x')
    table_outstock.configure(xscrollcommand=x_scrollbar.set)
```